# ImportError Circular dependency in Django

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I'm trying to solve a dependency problem on Django for my web API.
Lets consider 2 models in 2 apps.

**Areas App :**
*models.py*

```
class Room1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    step = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Project', blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**Areas App :**
*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from inventory.serializers import ProjectSerializer

class Room1Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    step = ProjectSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Room1
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'step')
```

**inventory App :**
*models.py*

```
class Inventory(models.Model): 
    identifier = models.CharField(ax_length=50, blank=False)
    place = models.ForeignKey('Areas.Room1', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Project(models.Model):
    Manip = models.CharField(max_length=30,  blank=False)
```

**inventory App :**
*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from inventory.models import *
from Areas.serializers import Room1Serializer

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'Manip')

class InventorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    place = Room1Serializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ('id','identifier', 'place')
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'ProjectSerializer'

The thing is that I'm importing *inventory.serializers* in my Areas/serializers
and also importing *Areas.serializers* in my inventory/serializers

Could you please share your experience ?

Thanks

Comment: Add your imports, not classes from files. The problem is about imports and not the classes.

Comment: If I go for a `import inventory.serializers` in my Areas\serializers.py it seems that my `ProjectSerializer()` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

> **inventory-->serializer.py here**
>
> > from Areas.serializers import Room1Serializer
>
> **area-->serializer.py here**
>
> > from inventory.serializers import ProjectSerializer

here is the circular import occured.  Those files keep the track of imported class recursively.

**Solution Approach:** Rempve the `InventorySerializer` or `ProjectSerializer` to another `.py` file.

You can also check the recursive import by this command **isort -rc**.
Here in details documentation to avoid `circular import` which is caused for `importing related` things. Hope this will help.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#imports

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to dependencies then your model should be...

**Area App: models.py**

```
class Room1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    step = models.ForeignKey('inventory.Project.give_field_which_you_want_to_relate', blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**inventory App: models.py**

```
class Inventory(models.Model): 
    identifier = models.CharField(ax_length=50, blank=False)
    place = models.ForeignKey('Areas.Room1.give_field_which_you_want_to_relate', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Project(models.Model):
    Manip = models.CharField(max_length=30,  blank=False)
```

**It means rather give model name as ForeignKey you should give field of that model which you want to relate as ForeignKey.**

So, dependencies will not create any time.

Comment: The ImportError doesn't come from my models.py actually they're working pretty fine. I have to found a solution to fix my serializers.py imports

Comment: Are you try to import like this way... " from .serializers import ProjectSerializer " ??